# Why RST was Sent When No Close() or Shutdown() Called?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, tcp

We are using LoadRunner to do press test on a tcp-based multi-threaded server application. Recently we encounter an annoying issue:

The clients get error reporting -- "10054 - connection reset by peer" after some cycles. By capturing packets from client,  we found clients receive RST from server.

**What strange is we don't call any close() or shutdown() from server side (for test purpose), the client still gets the RST packet and 10054 error?!!**

Below are the packets I caught:

1. 5395 77.335317000    192.168.11.232  192.168.11.30   TCP 62  27124→10000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2. 5656 77.356679000    192.168.11.30   192.168.11.232  TCP 60  10000→27124 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460
3. 5657 77.356684000    192.168.11.232  192.168.11.30   TCP 54  27124→10000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0
4. 5776 77.359276000    192.168.11.232  192.168.11.30   TCP 1514    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
5. 5778 77.359286000    192.168.11.232  192.168.11.30   HTTP/XML    332 POST /AddressBookController.php HTTP/1.1
6. 5901 77.368227000    192.168.11.30   192.168.11.232  TCP 60  10000→27124 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0

Here are my questions, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Q1. Why would the server send RST to the client **when it doesn't even call any close() or shutdown() to the socket from server side**?

Q2. [DUPLICATE Q1, Please Skip]In what condition will a RST be sent by the server when both the client and server haven't called any close() or shutdown?

Q3. Is it possible for me to recompile the kernel and print some log in the TCP stack? I want to know what happened when it sends a RST packet.

**[UPDATE]**
Increasing the listen(BACKLOG) FROM BackLog=100 to BackLog=1000, will dramatically decreases the errors from around 50/hour to 1~2/10hours. Why?

**[UPDATE2]**
 1. This is a gSOAP server which accepts soap request and returns around
        1~2 Kilobytes of data to clients.
     2. We checked the packets from client's side, there is no FIN flag from server which proves server never calls any close() or
    shutdown().
     3. We were using LoadRunner doing press test with 400 USERs make parallel soap requests, the frequency is 80 thousand requests per
    hour average.
     4. Contents of Packet 4 are nothing abnomal, below are part of it

```
POST /AddressBookController.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.11.30:10000
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1470
Connection: close
Cookie: sessionId=a23b15dcc14bb1d8f9f6bf3c4ed728d90c4c3939143866821152918211
SOAPAction: ""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
......
```

Comment: What was in packet 4?

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Why would the server send RST to the client while it doesn't even call any close() or shutdown() to the socket?

Because the server had decided to close the connection but the client kept sending. Or, the server closed its socket while there was still unread data.

> Q2. In what condition will a RST be sent by the server when both the client and server haven't called any close() or shutdown?

That's just the same question all over again.

> Q3. Is it possible for me to recompile the kernel and print some log in the TCP stack? I want to know what happened when it sends a RST packet.

No, you want to know what happened before it sent the RST packet.

The problem seems to be with your client. It should certainly close the connection at some point.

**EDIT** In this case it appears you have sent something odd (non-HTTP), in packet #4, which has caused the server to close the connection. What is it?

Comment: But In our case, we didn't call close() or shutdown in server side. Besides, we have checked there is no unread data because I replace the close() with something like while(read()). So how would that happen? Is there anything wrong with the packets?

Comment: Most likely cause, an unhandled dynamic element related to session or state data. Aged out or inappropriate data is handed to the server which then terminates the connection as not valid.

Comment: @JamesPulley That does cause a RST to be sent, but see the six packets, I don't see anything wrong with them, they were captured from the client.

Comment: What server is this? What does netstat show at the server host for the state of the connection (if any) after the RST? Have you really written your own HTTP server? Because that's the only way you can know whether it called `close()` or `shutdown()`, unless you had a debugger on it, or a system call trace.

Comment: Look at the HTTP Log and the HTTP error log for the connection in question.  You may find an excellent error text, such as "invalid session identifier" which would point to the reason for the reset.

Comment: @EJP We use gSOAP server, and we are sure the server never call shutdown or close(). We didn't record the status of the connection from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Refering your "packet 4" from (the formerly relevant) RFC 2616:

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example,
>
> ```
> Connection: close
> ```

So you seem to get what you requested.

Comment: maybe it's an error of content format, but since the server is not a HTTP server which means it won't parse its content by HTTP options, and it doesn't call close() or shutdown(), so this item doesn't seem to be the reason, right?

Comment: @Steve: Why not see what happens when the client does not send this line?